# how to disable form_widget

Tags: symfony, twig

I have a question I need to Disable a `form_widget` in twig. Because I wont to show alle users in a Table like this:

```
       <tbody>
            {% for einrichtungUsersForm in einrichtungUsersWithForm%}

            <tr>
                <td><a href="{url action=edit id=$item->id}">{{ einrichtungUsersForm.getEinrichtung().getNachname() }}</a></td>
                <td><a href="{url action=edit id=$item->id}">{{ einrichtungUsersForm.getEinrichtung().getVorname() }}</a></td>
                <td><a href="{url action=edit id=$item->id}">{{ einrichtungUsersForm.getEinrichtung().getEmail() }}</a></td>
                <td>
                    {{ form_widget(einrichtungUsersForm.getEinrichtungUserType().active )}}
                </td>
                {% if user != einrichtungUsersForm.getEinrichtung()%}
                <td><a href="{{ path('remove_user_einrichtung',{id: einrichtungUsersForm.getEinrichtung().getId()}) }}" class="confirm" data-confirm-title="Zugang löschen" data-confirm="Wollen Sie den Zugang für {{ einrichtungUsersForm.getEinrichtung().getVorname() }} {{ einrichtungUsersForm.getEinrichtung().getNachname() }}  wirklich löschen?">Zugang löschen</a></td>
                {% endif %}
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
```

But the user that is loading the Table needs the
`{{ form_widget(einrichtungUsersForm.getEinrichtungUserType().active )}}` disabled so that he can't set him safe unactive. Is that possible? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Even when you disable specific field in the frontend you would still need to alter the controller which is responsible to save the object to prevent from altering this property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add an 'attr' with

```
{{ form_widget(einrichtungUsersForm.getEinrichtungUserType().active, { 'attr': {'disabled': true}}) }}
```